# Create a postgres database within a docker-compose.yml file

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to create a postgres database named bank within a docker-compose.yml file just after the postgres container has started but when i run `docker-compose --env-file .env -f docker-compose.yaml up -d` i get this error: `/var/run/postgresql:5432 - no response`...

when i remove the line with the `command:` option, everything start correctly and i get: `/var/run/postgresql:5432 - accepting connections`

But now, i have to run this steps by steps in the terminal:

- docker exec -it postgres bash
- psql -U my_user_name
- create database bank;
- and exit

And i really don't want it to work like that, instead, i want the database to be created within the docker-compose file. (Note that, when i remove the `command:` option, and i run `until pg_isready; do sleep 1; done; echo accepting;` inside the container, it ouput `accepting` almost immediately)

The `POSTGRES_DB` env variable doesn't work, The username is still used as default

This is my docker-compose file:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - PGDATA=/data/postgres
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5332:5432"
    networks:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d postgres" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    command: /bin/bash -c "until pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -p 5432; do sleep 1; done; psql -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -c 'CREATE DATABASE bank;'"
networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db:
```

The most important line is the one with **command:** :

```yaml
command: /bin/bash -c "until pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -p 5432; do sleep 1; done; psql -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -c 'CREATE DATABASE bank;'"
```

Please help me with the correct command to execute so that the database will be created automatically when running `docker-compose --env-file .env -f file up -d`

Comment: The `command:` runs _instead of_ the standard image `CMD`; you are trying to create a table _instead of_ running a database.  If you can't use the standard environment variables or an initialization script then this needs to run in a separate container; tasks like creating tables are best done as part of your application's database migrations.

Comment: is the "create database" query used to create table ?

Comment: No, `CREATE DATABASE` and `CREATE TABLE` are separate SQL statements.

Comment: then why this: "you are trying to create a table instead of running a database. "

Comment: Because of the `command:` line, you are not running the PostgreSQL server but you are running the `psql` command instead; and since the database server is not running there is nothing for `psql` to connect to.  The SQL `CREATE DATABASE` statement (not "table", my mistake) can't execute because there's no database server running.

Comment: This is actually why I am here for

Answer (score 10):

Have you considered using the `POSTGRES_DB` environment variable ?

```yaml
services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: bank
    volumes:
      - db:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5332:5432"
    networks:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d postgres" ]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db:
```

Comment: I saw it on the postgres official images on hub. but it didn't work for me. the POSTGRES_USER is still used by default. I forgot to mention sorry

Comment: it didn't work, i get this error  FATAL:  role "root" does not exist, and a database is ceated using the postgres_user as name

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Love you

Comment: I think there was a typo in:

`test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres" ]`

I had 

`test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d postgres" ]`

and it was also giving me 

`FATAL: role "root" does not exist`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a create db script and add it as a volume, like this:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:15.3-alpine3.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes: 
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./create-db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_database.sql
    networks:
      - backnet
```

My SQL script is simple as this:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE some_database;
```

If you already have your volume initiated 'db', you'll need to erase it first (afaik) because postgres will declare that a database already exists and will skip initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another setup for creating local PG using `Docker`:

1. Create a file called `init.sql` containing your sql statements.
2. Create `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
# dump build stage
FROM postgres:11-alpine as dumper

COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN ["sed", "-i", "s/exec \"$@\"/echo \"skipping...\"/", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ENV PGDATA=/data

RUN ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh", "postgres"]

# final build stage
FROM postgres:11-alpine

COPY --from=dumper /data $PGDATA
```

3. Run the following command in the directory that `Dockerfile` resides:

```
docker image build . -t preloaded_db:latest
```

This will create a docker image with name `preloaded_db` and `latest` tag.

4. Run the `Docker` image with the following command:

```
docker container run -d --rm -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres --name test_preloaded_db preloaded_db:latest
```

[Here](https://cadu.dev/creating-a-docker-image-with-database-preloaded/) you can find the complete source for it.